# customized dynamic web forms

Tags: c#, asp.net, ajax, asp.net-mvc-3

I have a web form that has 2 drop down menus, when the first drop down menu chooses something, I want the next drop down menu to populate according to the selection on the first drop down menu without the page reloading.  Would I use ajax for this?  What is the best way to accomplish this?  Anyone have any good tutorials for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an example: http://www.highoncoding.com/Articles/770_Implementing_Dynamic_DropDownList_in_ASP_NET_MVC_3_Framework.aspx

Answer (score 1):

Of course you should use ajax.
JQuery provides you with this functionality.

Create a webservice and add to it a method that returns a list of a certain object.
in your javascript file, on the selectedindexchange of the first drop down list write the below

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    dataType: "json",
    url: WebServiceUrl/methodname,
    data: "{id: '" + id + "'}",
    success: LoadDataSuccedded,
    error: LoadDataFailure
});

function LoadDataSuccedded(result, e)
{
    var data = result.d;
    //fill the second drop down list
}

function LoadDataFailure(result, e)
{

}
```

check this link for more clarification http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/